# Can't get basic test to work in react-testing-utils with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I can't get a basic test working with react-test-utils and Redux as shown below.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

it('renders welcome message', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: combineReducers({}),
    })

    console.log(store)

    const { getByText } = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        </Provider>
    )
    expect(getByText('hi')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

it fails with this error

```
    Provider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

      14 |      console.log(store)
      15 | 
    > 16 |      const { getByText } = render(
         |                            ^
      17 |              <Provider store={store}>
      18 |                      <h1>hi</h1>
      19 |              </Provider>

      at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14348:23)
      at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16762:28)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17542:5)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18596:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
...
```

But if comment out the `<Provider>` like shown below then test passes

```js
it('renders welcome message', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: combineReducers({}),
    })

    console.log(store)

    const { getByText } = render(
        // <Provider store={store}>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        // </Provider>
    )
    expect(getByText('hi')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link with the same test?

Comment: @MukeshSoni I can't seem to get it reproducible in code sandbox. This is a boilerplate repo. Can I share this in a branch? It's pretty easy to run the code.

Comment: You could consider mocking your store using https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store. You could provide only needed pieces of your store considering the component under test. Works great.

Comment: Thanks @Flo but I don't want to mock the store.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify Provider as a wrapper to render method from react-testing library

```
it('renders welcome message', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: combineReducers({}),
    })

    console.log(store)
    const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
         return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
    }
    const { getByText } = render(
         <h1>hi</h1>, 
         {wrapper: Wrapper}
    )
    expect(getByText('hi')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

You could also overrider the testing-library's render method to make the Wrapper logic Generic as mentioned in the [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux)

```
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { initialState as reducerInitialState, reducer } from './reducer'

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState = reducerInitialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'

// override render method
export { render }
```

and use it like

```
// counter.test.js
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
// We're using our own custom render function and not RTL's render
// our custom utils also re-export everything from RTL
// so we can import fireEvent and screen here as well
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from './test-utils'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

it('renders welcome message', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: combineReducers({}),
    })

    const { getByText } = render(
            <h1>hi</h1>,
         {store}
    )
    expect(getByText('hi')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Please let me know if the above solution solves your problem or not

Comment: This gives the same error. Thanks for helping but it looks like your suggestion is just wrapping things differently.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider check the following dependencies in place, sometimes you need to uninstall and install as development, like react-dom case.

```
yarn add react-dom  // or npm i react-dom
yarn add redux
yarn add react-test-renderer
yarn remove react-dom
yarn add react-dom -D
yarn remove react-redux
yarn add react-redux
yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit
```

Your code runs on my machine without no issues

[image]

@Ryan as per your request here is the test.test.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

it('renders welcome message', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: combineReducers({}),
    })

    console.log(store)

    const { getByText } = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        </Provider>
    )
    expect(getByText('hi')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Feras i tried reinstalling those packages and it still didn't work on my box. Can you post the code for the test you ran? I don't see a `test.test.js` file? I don't see that in the repo